# viewcontroller inheritance

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I have 30+ viewcontroller in my project, and there is a behavior to be added in 28 of them.

When a button is clicked if 10 second not passed in that viewcontroller, I need to present a alertview sliding from top. (I have already implemented this behaviour for one of them)

But my question is, how can I inherit this behavior in a proper way for all of these viewcontrollers?

Googling this, but cannot find relavent solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all of your view controllers that need this functionality are subclasses of `UIViewController`, i.e. not `UITableViewController` or another subclass of `UIViewController`, you can create a subclass of `UIViewController`, say `ButtonClickAlertViewController` (or whatever makes sense) that implements the functionality you need to replicate. Then have all of the classes that need this functionality subclass your  `ButtonClickAlertViewController` class instead of `UIViewController`.

You may need to take into account how this specific functionality integrates into each of your individual view controller classes. For example, you may need a method in your `ButtonClickAlertViewController` class that signals a button has been clicked in order to check your timer and possibly display an alert. In each of your classes that subclass `ButtonClickAlertViewController`, you might need to call this method in each of the `IBAction` methods that your button click actions call.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass `UIViewController` and add your desired behavior for all view controllers and then subclass your existing view controllers from the viewController with the desired behavior.

Inheritance chain:

> UIViewController -> ViewControllerWithBehaviorForAll ->
>   YouExistingViewlContollersWhichNeedTheBehavior